# Kali 8 my Win 7 or Dual boot/5.3.0-kali-amd64/win 7(platform:HP G71-340US)

Tags: kali-linux, windows, dual-boot

Good news: Kali is working fine. The GRUB works A-OK for deploying Kali, and for all I know, all features are enabled.

The challenge: When I use GRUB to boot Windows 7. It boots, kind of. It boots, without MOST of the drivers to connect to its own hardware, and all of the third party software deleted. It DOES connect to the WiFi, however, web pages don't load right(basically not at all) and it doesn't think it has a DVD drive any more. Windows is broken. Not gone, but useless.

I would love  to make MS-Windows function, for the sake of doing a good job on my first Kali install ever.

My thoughts are to seek out each individual driver and install it piecemeal on the system(perhaps impossible, definitely painstaking).

I cannot, obviously, create a repair disc at this point in the operation, though I have learned to do so in the future.

Does the forum have any suggestions?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site. To get to your question, could you please edit it to only include the relevant portions of your issue? If I am understanding what you are asking for in this post is that you want to know how to configure Windows in your dual boot environment? That type of question would likely be better served the sister site, Superuser. Is your issue with Kali Linux or Windows? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your direction kemotep. See edit for approval. does this question belong in another forum?

Comment: Daily reminder that Kali isn't really for regular desktop use.  Most people are better off with Debian, Ubuntu or Mint.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. Thanks. I'm making some progress with some windows setings, so yes, probably a WinThang. I'm new. Studying Pentesting. Should I move this thread myself, or does one of your admins handle it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely not a Linux problem but a Windows problem.  It therefore ought to be passed somewhere like [superuser.com](https://superuser.com).  However I [personally believe in assisting with problems caused by installing Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/should-we-have-a-stock-answer-for-broken-windows-boot)... at least as far as explaining what just happened.

Your description sounds unusual, but I have a theory about what has happened to your system...

---

I think that yor [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) does not trust grub, and therefore when Windows is booted through grub it is unable to get *privileged* access to something related to [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management).  This might have the effect of messing up your DVD and even graphics drivers.  Re-installing them may not help.

---

**To test this theory**

I would start by trying to boot Windows directly.  Your boot loader is most likely stored in [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) not the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) meaning that the Windows boot loader should still be present and has not been overwritten by grub.  So you should be able to instruct your [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) to boot Windows instead of grub.

The way of doing this varies between different BIOS, as a hint I'd try pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> repeatedly as your machine is powering on.  Failing that every BIOS I know uses one of <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> to get into the settings, so you should be able to chose an OS to boot there.

*If Windows boots perfectly this way with all it's drivers then you know that your problem is definitely to do with booting via grub.*

---

If that is your problem then I would look to see if Kali has a signed grub installer.  With any luck this might be a package called `grub-efi-amd64-signed`.  This *should* be signed with a key that your BIOS will accept and thus *might* fix your problem.

If you can get the package then after installing it don't forget to run:

```
grub-install
```